# Getting detailed step information from via MS Band Cloud API OR ...?

Tags: microsoft-band

I've been putting together a mechanism to sync activity data collected by the MS Band with our backend via the cloud API and getting all the boilerplate setup for the OAuth flows...  The intent being to periodically run this data through our backend processes to categorise periods of meaningful walk based activity.

I've been experimenting with the data available and as far as I can tell we cannot get access to the raw step data (or at a fine grained level )?  We have successfully been able to request summary info by hour/day, however this is not fit for our purpose.

What I'd like is to access step data in the form `[startTimeStamp,endTimeStamp,stepsTaken,...]`  where each record represents a continuous period of movement by the wearer.

We would also be able to work with data summarised by minute as this would give enough context to our use case.

Is this possible via the cloud API? or are there any plans to implement the Period "**Minute**" on the summary API endpoint?

```
https://api.microsofthealth.net/v1/me/Summaries/Minute?startTime=2015-12-09T14%3A00%3A00.369Z
```

If this isn't possible perhaps there is another way to make this data available? (via HealthKit on iOS or Fit on Android?)

As a complete alternate perhaps it might be possible to get the accumulated step data detail from the band via bluetooth in a similar fashion to the native MS Health App?

We already use the SDK to stream realtime Heart Rate data during user cardio sessions, but there appears to be no way to extract the historical step info from the band directly.

Thanks!

Comment: If you need this too, I've added a request for cloud API summaries to be available for the period "Minute" here : https://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/forums/283636-microsoft-health-and-microsoft-band/suggestions/11051913-provide-access-to-finer-grained-step-tracking-data  - Please upvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Band itself monitors and logs the steps over time. When sync'ing, that log is transferred to the Cloud via the Microsoft Health app. The app then pulls the "steps for the day" from the Health service.

These logs are not exposed to apps via the SDK. The only way to calculate steps per custom short period yourself is to have your app sample the counter in the background on a frequent enough basis in order to do the calculation.

Comment: Unfortunately for our use case this would likely require significant battery draw to be in continuous sample/listen mode (Not to mention the complexity involved when attempting to keep an app alive and listening in the background with the various platforms app lifecycle constraints).  Given that the step log is pushed to the cloud - is it not planned to expose summary data by minute?

Comment: You should ask for this feature in the dedicated UserVoice https://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/forums/283636-microsoft-health-and-microsoft-band

Comment: Thanks, done! - https://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/forums/283636-microsoft-health-and-microsoft-band/suggestions/11051913-provide-access-to-finer-grained-step-tracking-data

Comment: Don't forget ton check ;)